# ESP8266 using DS3231 to wake up from deep sleep

Tags: esp8266, low-power, interrupts, rtc

I am using the Arduino IDE to program the ESP8266 and am able to set the time, alarms on the DS3231 and test to see that they are firing.

My problem is that I would like to use the SQW output to wake the ESP8266 from deepsleep(0).

I have attempted to connect the SQW to the RST and interrupt pins with no luck.

Ideally I would like to have some help with:

1. wiring diagram
2. preferred libraries
3. an example sketch to make the system work

My goal is to set the DS3231 alarms to wake the ESP8266 at specified times, take measurements, reset the alarm and go back to sleep with the aim to extend the battery life.

Thus far I have accomplished this by having the chip wake-up every hour, check the time, go back to sleep, repeat until correct time.  It would be so much easier if I could just let the DS3231 alarms do the job.  I am running the DS3231 with the coin battery and the ESP8266 with a battery.

Stefan Wyss addressed the answer in a previous post on Feb 21, 2020, but I don't know how to touch base with him for a more complete solution.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome John - this is asking too many questions in one, and you won't get the things you are asking for here. Show what you have tried, your attempts to solve the problem, and finally why you are stuck. You can edit this question, or delete and try again :)

Comment: Seems I may have duplicated your question, but I got an answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/644698/288848